# JCL Job for z/OS to execute SRCHFOR or LISTCAT for datasets

Tags: jobs, mainframe, zos, jcl, tso

I need to create a batch job for searching a data set list; I need to submit the job over FTP.

I am a complete newbie in JCL, so could anyone help me with an example job with SRCHFOR-command?

I need to also create a job for the IDCAMS utility command `Listcat`

I would be really thankful only for an example job.

Comment: Have you talked to your sysprogs?  JCL job headers are often site specific. And what have you tried so far?  Googling SRCHFOR comes up with several examples.

Comment: For example, have you looked at http://mainframewiki.com/tips-tricks/search-using-srchfor.html?  I'd also suggest asking the LISTCAT question separately, as they're different utilities and do different things.  Unless you're asking for help with JCL in general, which is a different question.

Answer (score 3):

Given you indicated you don't know where to start here is a sample job that will run the search in the first step and run IDCAMS to execute a Listcat in the second step.

This [link](http://mainframewiki.com/tips-tricks/search-using-srchfor.html) has some useful information on SuperC.

**Note:** Your jobcard will need to be customized based on your installation's requirements.  This job can be submitted via FTP and the subsequent output can be retrieved via FTP as well.

```
//SRCHCMP  JOB (CCCCCCCC),'HOGSTROM',                   
//             MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                          
//             MSGCLASS=O,                              
//             CLASS=A,                                 
//             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                           
//*                                                     
//SRCHFOR  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=('SRCHCMP,ANYC')       
//NEWDD   DD   DSN=USER1.TEST.CNTL,DISP=SHR             
//OUTDD   DD   SYSOUT=*                                 
//SYSIN   DD     *                                      
 SRCHFOR 'NEWDD'                                        
/*                                                      
//*                                                     
//IDCAMS   EXEC PGM=IDCAMS                              
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                  
//SYSIN    DD *                                         
 LISTCAT ENTRY('USER1.TEST.CNTL') ALL                   
/*                                                      
//
```

Output from the first step will look like this:

```
ISRSUPC   -   MVS/PDF FILE/LINE/WORD/BYTE/SFOR COMPARE UTILITY- ISPF  
FOR z/OS         2019/02/26  22.45    PAGE     1               LINE-#   
SOURCE SECTION                    SRCH DSN: USER1.TEST.CNTL             


                                                                                                                                      SRCHFOR                     --------- STRING(S) FOUND
-------------------                                                          

      8  //NEWDD   DD   DSN=USER1.TEST.CNTL,DISP=SHR                                                                                
     11   SRCHFOR 'NEWDD'                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                       ISRSUPC   -   MVS/PDF FILE/LINE/WORD/BYTE/SFOR COMPARE UTILITY- ISPF
FOR z/OS         2019/02/26  22.45    PAGE     2             
     SEARCH-FOR SUMMARY SECTION            SRCH DSN: USER1.TEST.CNTL                                                                
                                                                                                                                     LINES-FOUND  LINES-PROC  MEMBERS-W/LNS  MEMBERS-WO/LNS  COMPARE-COLS 
LONGEST-LINE                                                  
        2         4436            1             41           1:80           80                                                      
                                                                                                                                     PROCESS OPTIONS USED: ANYC                                            

                                                                                                                                     THE FOLLOWING PROCESS STATEMENTS (USING COLUMNS 1:72) WERE PROCESSED: 

    SRCHFOR 'NEWDD'
```

Output from the IDCAMS Listcat looks like this:

```
IDCAMS  SYSTEM SERVICES                                           TIME: 22:45:34        02/26/19     PAGE      1 

 LISTCAT ENTRY('USER1.TEST.CNTL') ALL                                                                            
NONVSAM ------- USER1.TEST.CNTL                                                                                  
     IN-CAT --- CATALOG.T70502                                                                                   
     HISTORY                                                                                                     
       DATASET-OWNER-----(NULL)     CREATION--------2017.089                                                     
       RELEASE----------------2     EXPIRATION------0000.000                                                     
       ACCOUNT-INFO-----------------------------------(NULL)                                                     
     SMSDATA                                                                                                     
       STORAGECLASS -----CLASS2     MANAGEMENTCLASS---(NULL)                                                     
       DATACLASS --------(NULL)     LBACKUP ---0000.000.0000                                                     
     ENCRYPTIONDATA                                                                                              
       DATA SET ENCRYPTION-----(NO)                                                                              
     VOLUMES                                                                                                     
       VOLSER------------T70502     DEVTYPE------X'3010200F'     FSEQN------------------0                        
     ASSOCIATIONS--------(NULL)                                                                                  
     ATTRIBUTES                                                                                                  
IDCAMS  SYSTEM SERVICES                                           TIME: 22:45:34        02/26/19     PAGE      2 
         THE NUMBER OF ENTRIES PROCESSED WAS:                                                                    
                   AIX -------------------0                                                                      
                   ALIAS -----------------0                                                                      
                   CLUSTER ---------------0                                                                      
                   DATA ------------------0                                                                      
                   GDG -------------------0                                                                      
                   INDEX -----------------0                                                                      
                   NONVSAM ---------------1                                                                      
                   PAGESPACE -------------0                                                                      
                   PATH ------------------0                                                                      
                   SPACE -----------------0                                                                      
                   USERCATALOG -----------0                                                                      
                   TAPELIBRARY -----------0                                                                      
                   TAPEVOLUME ------------0                                                                      
                   TOTAL -----------------1                                                                      
         THE NUMBER OF PROTECTED ENTRIES SUPPRESSED WAS 0                                                        
IDC0001I FUNCTION COMPLETED, HIGHEST CONDITION CODE WAS 0                                                        

IDC0002I IDCAMS PROCESSING COMPLETE. MAXIMUM CONDITION CODE WAS 0
```

Here is a [reference to the SuperC utility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.f54u200/axe.htm)

Comment: In addition to the above, ```ftp <IP address> /n <User ID> /n <Password> /n quote site filetype=jes /n put jcl.txt``` can be coded as a .txt file in Windows environment and could be saved as a batch file. Triggerring the batch file would submit a job in JCL via FTP. Note: replace /n with a new line, as I'm not able to press enter in COmments; Don't include '<, >' tags in the text file, I've shown them for better clarity; jcl.txt is the text file with JCL having srchfor and LISTCAT in batch.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach, if you are more familiar with the Unix side of the house, would be to consider doing these things via USS or TSO. For USS (Unix System Services), check out my blog:

https://makingdeveloperslivesbetter.wordpress.com/2019/01/06/mvs-utilities-an-almost-real-world-example/

If nothing else, reading the code for the various utilities (they are mostly just shell scripts) will help you map from Unix concepts to z/OS (MVS) concepts.

Comment: EXcept for the link this "answer" reads more like a comment - it would be greatly improved if it included the relevant details from the linked article.